# reading next lines from a file after particular pattern

Tags: java, file

I have to read a file if some pattern occurs that file i **have to read next lines** of the text file in java

```
while (sc1.hasNextLine()){
    String a = sc1.nextLine();
    String b = sc1.nextLine();
    if(a.contains("pattern")){
        //read next lines
    }
}
```

Comment: You should ask a question by the way, I answer you but I should have not with th current state of the question. See [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To simply read the file to find the line you want, just use a loop until you reach the end or the pattern your want like this :

```
while(sc1.hastNextLine() && !sc.nextLine().contains("pattern")){
    //skip
}
```

then you just have to check if there is still a line to read

```
if (sc1.hastNextLine()){
    //read the line
}
```